# Bug in evaluating the velocity autocorrelation function

Tags: python, simulation, autocorrelation

I am running a molecular dynamics simulation (with a Lennard-Jones fluid), and I want to evaluate the velocity autocorrelation function for my simulation.
I am running a simulation with $N$ particles, and the simulation is going from time $t=0$ to $t=(n_{max}-1)\Delta t$ in time steps of $\Delta t$.
In my simulation, I store my particle velocities in a $N \times 3$ numpy array, where each row $i$ is the velocity vector of particle $i$. This velocity vector is defined in my code as `currentBox.particleVelocities`.

As I run my simulation, I store my velocity vectors at each time point in memory to be used later, in a list called `particleVelocityList`. Basically, `particleVelocityList[2]` is the N-by-3 numpy array holding all the velocities of my particles at time $2\Delta t$.

This is my code:

```
for i in range(nmax):
    for j in range(nmax-i):
        ACF[j] = ACF[j] + np.sum(particleVeclocityList[i]*particleVeclocityList[j+i])
    #
    ACF[i] = ACF[i]/(nmax-i)
#
```

However, when I run my code, I don't get the right results.
This is the plot I get: [image]

This is the plot I expect: [image]

Up to some normalization factor.

The "expected image" has the formula for the velocity ACF.

I consistently have a problem at exactly the midway point. It plateaus and hugs zero. Never goes south of that or oscillates, like it is supposed to. Any idea what might be going wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The storage step for the storage of the velocity and the coordinates can be decreased further to make it discontinuous i.e. dump the coordinates
and velocity at even shorter timesteps. Otherwise, the code seemed ok.